# How to sum horizontal cells based on the value of the cell to their right in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, lookup

I'm trying to summarize monthly "hours worked" data. Each row is formatted as this example. This example is one week for two employees

```
Louie, 8, solar, 9, service, 8, solar, 8, solar, 7, service    
Chuck, 8, solar, 8, solar, 8, solar, 9, service, 8, solar
```

I want to be able to calculate that:

Louie worked 24 hours in solar and 16 hours in service.

Chuck worked 32 hours in solar and 9 hours in service.

It is formatted this way, so that I can summarize daily hours worked in solar, or service for all employees on a daily basis. This is easy with a sumif function. To calculate this weekly or monthly has me stumped. Is there a function or do I need to store my data differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT():

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:J1,--(B1:K1="solar"))
```

For Service Change the `"solar"` to `"service"`

Comment: Thanks Scott, this solved my problem. Very interesting function!